# Getting Invalid Date for date string as "19-02-2020" and date format "DD-MM-YYYY"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date, datetime

When page is loaded, my input box gets automatically populated with a date time. This date time can be in any valid format like `DD-MMM-YYYY - HH:mm`, `MMM DD, YYYY - HH:mm`, etc and I wanted to pick up this date, parse it and add some hours to it.
But when I try to parse a date which is something like `19-02-2020 - 00:00` (`DD-MM-YYYY - HH:mm`), it gives me an invalid Date.
I have tried

```
new Date('19-02-2020 - 23:00')
// output - Invalid Date
```

and also tried using moment JS to format the date like

```
moment("19-02-2021 - 23:00","DD-MM-YYYY - HH:mm").toDate();
// output - Fri Feb 19 2021 23:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

but now all the other dates will be parsed wrong like this one

```
moment("19-02-2021 - 23:00","DD-MMM-YYYY - HH:mm").toDate();
// output - Tue Jan 19 2021 23:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Is there a correct and reliable way to do this?

Comment: *can be in any valid format* - well you need to know what format it is to correctly parse it. What if I enter `-895-8-FSSsd-#8893` and claim it's my secret encoded date format?

Comment: why did you use `-MMM-` on the second example?

Comment: Also, what process is 'automatically populating' the input box? if you had some clarity on that, it would make your job easier.

Comment: It is guaranteed that the format will be valid. Do I have to handle all formats differently ? or is there a universal way to parse any format ?

Comment: @TKoL `-MMM-` is also part of a valid date format but I did not get the correct result s while using moment JS

Comment: @TKoL that's a script that runs on page load and populates the input box.

Comment: @SarthakSharma of course you didn't get the correct result, the date you passed to it is in `-MM-` format, not `-MMM-`. So what does the code look like in that script that runs on page load? How is it populating that field? What date format is it using?

Comment: It just seems odd that you have a script that 'automatically inputs a date' but you can't say anything more specific about that date other than 'its a valid format'. Why does the script not use the same format every time?

Comment: @TKoL The format of the date is config-driven and can change anytime. But I would know what format was being used to populate the date so that I can parse it again

Answer (score 0):

[`Date` constructor accepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#timestamp_string) ISO 8601 and RFC 2822 date/time formats:

```js
let dates = [
  new Date('2020-02-19T23:00Z'),
  new Date('2020-02-19 23:00Z'),
  new Date('Wed Feb 19 2020 23:00:00 UTC'),
]
console.log(dates)
```

When your date/time information has fixed nonstandard format, you can use regular expressions to convert it to RFC 3339 format and then parse it:

```js
let rfc3339 = "19-02-2020 - 00:00".replace(/(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*) - (\d*):(\d*)/, (_, d, m, y, h, min) => `${y}-${m}-${d}T${h}:${min}Z`);
let date = new Date(rfc3339);
console.log(date)
```

You can combine this into one function:

```js
function parseDate(dateStr) {
  const re = /(\d\d)(, |-)(\d\d)\2(\d\d\d\d) - (\d\d):(\d\d)/;

  let groups = re.exec(dateStr);

  if (groups == null) {
    return null; // on invalid input
  }

  let rfc3339Str;
  if (groups[2] == '-') {
    rfc3339Str = `${groups[4]}-${groups[3]}-${groups[1]}T${groups[5]}:${groups[6]}Z`;
  } else {
    rfc3339Str = `${groups[4]}-${groups[1]}-${groups[3]}T${groups[5]}:${groups[6]}Z`;
  }

  let date = new Date(rfc3339Str);
  return date;
}

for (dateStr of [
    '04, 23, 2020 - 12:34',
    '23-04-2020 - 12:34',
  ]) {
  console.log(parseDate(dateStr));
}
```

Comment: Dates constructor gives me invalid date for  `new Date("19-02-2021 - 23:22")`. How to parse when my date String is `"19-02-2021 - 23:22"`

Comment: You'll need probably custom parsing routine. Wait a moment, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: The second example format is not supported by ECMA-262 and produces an invalid Date in some implementations.

Answer (score 0):

the Date string format is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` where `T` is a delimiter and `Z` reffer to the timezone (optional).

`HH:mm:ss.sss`  is equivalent to: hours, minutes, seconds ,and milliseconds.

```js
const date = new Date( Date.parse('2021-02-19T00:05:00.000') );
console.log(date)
```

Learn more about Date object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I have tried this too but its unable to parse my date string. `new Date(Date.parse("19-02-2021 - 23:22"))`

Comment: because you are passing the date string in a wrong format. Try `new Date(Date.parse("19-02-2021T23:22:00"))`

Comment: The one that you have mentioned also gives invalid date.